# Maven conflict between interface and class with same naming and packaging

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, package

I have 2 projects to be merged in one maven project

One project has a java class with name

```
com.xyz.XyzManager
```

and the other project has an interface with the name

```
com.xyz.XyzManager
```

in the code I use

```
XyzManager manager = new XyzManagerImpl();
```

where XyzManagerImpl is an implementation of the interface

and also in the same code I use

```
XyzManager manager = new XyzManager();
```

where I use the class not the interface

I get compilation errors when I incluse both projects as it has conflict either when I use XyzManager as an interface or XyzManager as a java class

hope the issue is explained clear

Comment: Can you explain your definition of merge? Are you putting all sources into the same project, or are you combining the contents of two jars into a single jar?

Comment: I'm not merging jars, I'm only merging 2 projects into one parent project